I cant click the heart button with Shadow DOM
i try to program a like bot. but i cant click the button. I tried my best, can  you help me?enter image description hereenter image description here
can someone look after my screenshots and and the script and help me please?
i dont know what to do. i will login, open the profil but dont like the picture.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Account credentials
accounts = [
    {"username": "......", "password": "......."}
]

def login_and_click_photo_card(driver, username, password):
    print("Navigating to login page...")
    driver.get('https://4based.com/login')

    try:
        # Wait for the email input field to be visible and type the email
        print("Waiting for the email input field...")
        email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email'))
        )
        email_field.click()
        email_field.clear()
        email_field.send_keys(username)
        print("Email entered successfully.")

        # Wait for the password input field to be visible and type the password
        print("Waiting for the password input field...")
        password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password'))
        )
        password_field.click()
        password_field.clear()
        password_field.send_keys(password)
        print("Password entered successfully.")

        # Press "Enter" to submit the form
        print("Pressing Enter to submit the form...")
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        print("Enter key pressed successfully.")

        # Wait for the "Nein danke" button and click it
        print("Waiting for the 'Nein danke' button...")
        nein_danke_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ion-button[contains(., 'Nein danke')]"))
        )
        nein_danke_button.click()
        print("'Nein danke' button clicked successfully.")

        # Navigate directly to the profile page
        print("Navigating to the profile page...")
        driver.get('https://4based.com/profile/stellasolamente')
        print("Successfully navigated to the profile page.")

        # Wait for the first "file-stack-card" element and click it
        print("Waiting for the first 'file-stack-card' element to be clickable...")
        first_photo_card = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "file-stack-card.virtual-item"))
        )
        first_photo_card.click()
        print("First 'file-stack-card' clicked successfully.")

        # Wait for 2 seconds to observe the result
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Waited for 2 seconds after clicking the photo card.")

        # Use JavaScript to scroll the window by 200 pixels
        print("Attempting to scroll down the window by 200 pixels...")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 200);")
        print("Scroll down by 200 pixels completed.")

        # Access the Heart button in the Shadow DOM
        print("Accessing the Heart button in the Shadow DOM...")
        
        # Find the outer shadow host element
        shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ion-button[name='heart-outline']")
        shadow_root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadow_host)

        # Traverse deeper into the Shadow DOM if needed
        icon_wrapper = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.icon-inner")
        heart_icon = icon_wrapper.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg")
        
        # Click the heart icon using JavaScript
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", heart_icon)
        print("Heart button clicked successfully using JavaScript.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        time.sleep(30)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    login_and_click_photo_card(webdriver.Chrome(), 'email@email.com', 'password')

can someone help me with the code?
